# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Dengue'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting an error as indicated below. I do not understand the problem. I want to create a machine learning web application with Flask. The web application is going to predict the health status of a patient. I have diseases and symptoms dataset, but 'disease' column produces error. Maybe the code block which includes "label encoder" causes the error. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../dataset.csv')

X=df.loc[:,['Symptom_1','Symptom_2','Symptom_3','Symptom_4','Symptom_5','Symptom_6','Symptom_7','Symptom_8','Symptom_9','Symptom_10','Symptom_11']]
y=df.loc[:,['Disease']]

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
encoder=LabelEncoder()
X.loc[:,['Symptom_1','Symptom_2','Symptom_3','Symptom_4','Symptom_5','Symptom_6','Symptom_7','Symptom_8','Symptom_9','Symptom_10','Symptom_11']]=\
X.loc[:,['Symptom_1','Symptom_2','Symptom_3','Symptom_4','Symptom_5','Symptom_6','Symptom_7','Symptom_8','Symptom_9','Symptom_10','Symptom_11']].apply(encoder.fit_transform)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor  # I'm getting the error in this code block.
model=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_predict=model.predict(X_test)
```

***The error:***

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-5fee489fde7a> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
      2 model=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
----> 3 model=model.fit(X_train,y_train)
      4 y_predict=model.predict(X_test)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    331 
    332         if getattr(y, "dtype", None) != DOUBLE or not y.flags.contiguous:
--> 333             y = np.ascontiguousarray(y, dtype=DOUBLE)
    334 
    335         if expanded_class_weight is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in ascontiguousarray(a, dtype)
    175 
    176     """
--> 177     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order='C', ndmin=1)
    178 
    179 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Dengue'
```

Comment: Do you understand why `Dengue` is not convertible to a float? Do you understand why it's trying to convert that string to a float in the first place? Have you looked at where it occurs in your `dataset.csv` to see if it is out of place, or mis-formatted, or you're importing it wrongly?

Comment: Looks like you applied an encoder to the X values, but not the y values.

Comment: @Useless I wonder how enlightening it's going to be to OP for you to issue a series of insistent questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also use LabelEncoder() on your y. In fact, it is specifically to encode labels (y), not features (X), as stated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). If you give me more details about what your X and y look like (before encoding) I can give you a better answer.